# Button can be enabled only if textbox AND datetimepicker is filled

Tags: c#, datetimepicker, windows-forms-designer

[Edited Version based on replies]

I would like the button1 to be enabled only if both textbox and datetimepicker are filled. I am able to do for the text but not for datetimepicker. Here is my full code. FYI: my datetimepicker is being formatted to empty initially to allow user to choose a date himself.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Inspection
  {
    public partial class Vdetails : Form
     {
    public Vdetails()

    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Vnew.Enabled = false; 
    }

    //Allow user input date
    private void DTafes_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DTafes.CustomFormat = @"";
    }
    private void DTfa_ValueChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DTfa.CustomFormat = @"";
    }
    private void DTfe_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DTfe.CustomFormat = @"";
    }

    //Condition to allow button to go next
    private void ActivateButton()
    {
        Button1.Enabled = (Vehicle.Text != "" && Distance.Text != "");
    }

    private void Vehicle_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ActivateButton();
    }

    private void Distance_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ActivateButton();
    }
}
```

What and how do I add the code to allow for datetimepicker to be filled. Hope that someone could help me.

Comment: Where is the date time picker?

Comment: There are two textchanged-functions, but the datetimepicker does not have a textchanged-event. Can you provide the code where the eventhandlers get attached? (InitializeComponent in YourForm.Designer.cs)

Comment: Also i think it would be good practice you name your components with names, that contain the type of the component, so other people can see what distance and vehicle really are. Like textBoxVehicle and dateTimePickerDistnace. Is Distance really a datetimepicker? Seems a little bit weird with the naming

Comment: a DTP is always "filled"

Comment: Hai guys. Code edited accordingly. Do advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

DateTimePicker is always got a value but you can listen to the ValueChanged event

```
private bool dateChanged;
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    dateChanged = false;
    button1.Enabled = false;
}

private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dateChanged = true;
    SetEnabledness();
}

private void SetEnabledness()
{
    button1.Enabled = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text) && dateChanged;
}

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetEnabledness();
}
```

If you have more than one DateTimePicker you can use a HashSet instead of a bool (just make sure you wire up all the ValueChangedEvents to dp_ValueChanged e.g.

```
    private HashSet<DateTimePicker> dateChanged = new HashSet<DateTimePicker>();
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        dateChanged.Clear();
        button1.Enabled = false;

        dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
        dateTimePicker2.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
        dateTimePicker3.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
        dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = @" ";
        dateTimePicker2.CustomFormat = @" ";
        dateTimePicker3.CustomFormat = @" ";
    }

    private void dp_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var dp = (DateTimePicker) sender;
        dp.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short;
        dateChanged.Add(dp);
        SetEnabledness();
    }

    private void SetEnabledness()
    {
        button1.Enabled = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text) && dateChanged.Count == 3;
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetEnabledness();
    }
```

Comment: Hi Thomas. Appreciate the fast reply. The code worked but with certain exceptions. Just some background info. I 'emptied out' the datetime picker through this youtube vid: **https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xIaWEeYTJkw&lc=z22jelk50x3tfvz30acdp432wpu1hi5mv4lwetvthohw03c010c** So,1) I've written `dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = @"";` for each datetimepicker mentioned. This allow user to see empty and enter input. 2) In my case I got 3 datetimepicker and your method only works for one datetimepicker . So yeah, this is the issue. Hope you can help. Apart from that, the rest works nicely :)

Comment: Hey, I have updated the post to cover multiple pickers.

Comment: Hi Thomas. Ive followed exactly as yours and the new code has no error. However, after filling all the textbox and datetimepicker, the next button still wasn't enabled.

Comment: Did you make sure all 3 date pickers have ValueChanged set to dp_ValueChanged ? Can you stick a break point in the ValueChanged method and run in debugger.

Answer (score 0):

The dateTimePicker has no textchanged-event. There will never be an empty string inside the dateTimePicker. (Maybe you can set it via code, but not by user-input) You can use the valueChanged-event of the dateTimePicker to do something when the date was changed by the user.

Since the text will never be empty, you dont have to check it in you ActiveButton-function.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void ActiveateButton()
    {
        this.button1.Enabled = textBox1.Text != string.Empty;
    }


    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ActiveateButton();
    }
    private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ActiveateButton();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Olli. Appreciate the fast reply. Just some background info. I 'emptied out' the datetime picker through this youtube vid: **https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xIaWEeYTJkw&lc=z22jelk50x3tfvz30acdp432wpu1hi5mv4lwetvthohw03c010c** So this code did not work as the datetimepicker was initially empty and therefore the button was still enabled even when the date was empty. Thanks for your effort :)